# Google Play Services sign in

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-games

Пробую прикрутить плей сервисы по этому [туториалу](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/google-play-game-services-leaderboards--cms-20700)

При входе в приложение появляется табличка входа в Google Play Игры.

Можно как-то сделать так, чтобы это все было в фоне, без появления этой таблички ?

От сервиса игр мне нужно только - leaderboards..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If your game activity calls `connect()` in `onStart()`,  **the `GoogleApiClient` will attempt to sign in silently**. If the user signed in successfully before and has not signed out, the system calls the `onConnected()` method. If sign in fails, the system calls the `onConnectionFailed()` method.

– [Источник: *Implementing Sign-in in Your Android Game*](https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin) (жирный шрифт мой)

Полагаю, вам нужно именно это, "silent login". Совсем без участия игрока его не провернуть, и это правильно. Для этого необходимо, чтобы:

- Игрок уже логинился через окошко ранее
- С последнего логина игрок не разлогинивался

И судя по материалу за ссылкой, достаточно вызывать `connect()` (от `GoogleApiClient`) в `onStart()` (собственного `Activity`). Если все условия для "silent login" соблюдены, то соединение и так установится, а если нет, то либо необходим вход "с окном", либо вход просто невозможен (интернета нет, например).

Это **независимо** от того, какие части Google Play Games Services вам реально нужны.

Comment: спасибо за отклик. Дело в том, что я не вызываю GoogleApiClient.connect(); Все, что я в это активити делаю - наследуюсь от BaseGameUtils.

Comment: @researcher это ж [не активити](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/basegameutils/BaseGameUtils.java), а множественного наследования в Java нет.

Comment: Прошу прощения, имел ввиду BaseGameActivity.

Comment: Посмотрел несколько примеров и там не использует наследование от BaseGameActivity. А используют GoogleApiClient. Может надо отказаться от BaseGameActivity?

Comment: @researcher значит, уже должно работать, т. к. onStart приводит в onStart [класса `GameHelper`](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper.java).

Comment: Спасибо! А Вы не знаете где в приложении мне нужно добавлять Client ID и зачем он нужен? Все, что я указала в приложении это - app_id в /ids.xml. Приложение делает sign in. Может client_id нужен для leaderboards?

Comment: @researcher не думаю. А где упоминается?